# FileIterator has no results when searching with the name of a newly created file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The following code is giving me the error:

> Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.

I do not understand why; it seems like `NewSpreadSheetFile.next()` should return the `newSS` SpreadSheet.

```
function isEmptyFile(FileName) {
  var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('Hey');
  var NewSpreadSheetFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Hey');
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.open(NewSpreadSheetFile.next());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because the file hasn't had a chance to be created.  Add a sleep timer between `.create` and `.getFilesByName` and the function processes correctly.

```
function isEmptyFile(FileName) {
  var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('Hey');
  Utilities.sleep(1000)
  var NewSpreadSheetFile = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Hey');
  var spr = SpreadsheetApp.open(NewSpreadSheetFile.next());
  }
```